# codeigniter and tiny_mce wrong input

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce

I'm trying to use tiny_mce along with my codeigniter application. However, it looks like codeigniter escape almost everything from the textarea, how can i fix this?

I'm using the form helper and the form validation for the textaera form.

What should i do?

Comment: can provide some example? Like what you key in, and how's the output looks like?

Comment: may be stripcslashes() will help you to un-escape them ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this [thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/141495/) shows some solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using XSS filtering in CodeIgniter, you may find it strips out the code Tiny creates. `$this->input->post('string', true)` is XSS filtered, remove the `true` boolean to stop it.